# Sulu: add a new locatlistation leads to permission error

Tags: symfony, sulu

I wanted to give sulu a try and so far it looks nice. So installed a minimal version via composer, defined some page templates and everything worked so far. Then i added a new localization as described in http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/book/webspaces.html and http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/book/localization.html. Which is not working.

As described i simply added `<localization language="de" default="false"/>` to the list. But i cannot access the content of the new locale and moreover the starting page content.

The error i retrieve is a permission error:

```
Operation forbidden The available permissions are not sufficient for this operation
```

I've checked the permissions and every available permission is granted to the user. Now i am stuck.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you don't have these permissions in the correct locale. The User Role only describes what the user is allowed to do, but it doesn't describe in which language. That's because we don't want to have uncontrolled of user roles. Imagine you have a big homepage, with english, german and french content, then you would have to create three roles: Content Manager EN, Content Manager DE and Content Manager FR. We have chosen a different way.

In a user role you don't describe in which language these permissions apply, you do that on the user instead. Go to Contacts, select the contact with your user, and choose the permissions tab.

[image]

In the permissions section on this page you see a table with all the roles, the one being assigned are checked. The dropdown on the right describes to which language this applies. You probably haven't assigned the language to your new user here.